# npm g-i-s package and saving the results into a variable

Tags: node.js, npm, google-image-search

im trying to use g-i-s npm package.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/g-i-s)
Im trying to get the results into a variable but i think that becuse the gis is using callback function i cant input it into a variable and use await statement.
some one can help me to understand how can i use the results and put in into a var?

```js
var gis = require('g-i-s');
gis('cats', logResults);

function logResults(error, results) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, '  '));
  }
}
```